# how to get just what I need by JQuery and JQueryUI (i.e.: I don't want to import them)

Tags: javascript

I literally have a script like this:

```
$(function() {
         $( sliderRange ).slider({
             range: true,
             min: 0,
             max: time2 - time1,
             values: [ 0, time2 - time1 ],
             slide: function( event, ui ) {
                ...
             }
         });
      });
```

which forms a tiny part of a complex web app.

The whole web app. does not need either JQuery or JQueryUI (which the snippet above requires)

It's annoying to think that I must use JQuery and JQueryUI just for that tiny bit.
Is there a way to figure out the bit of code that I would have to import (since I probably use 2% of their functionality I'd rather get that 2% of the code inlined)

Comment: Well, for jQuery UI, you can choose which parts of it you want: http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: minified version of the entire jquery library is 32KB.you can use that.  its much compact and you get all the goodness of jquery

Comment: Use `<input type="range" />` if you don't need to support IE. But, including jQuery shouldn't be a problem since the user with probably have it cached already (assuming you're including from a CDN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it really helps you out or not, but you could always conditionally load the jQuery library from the CDN only when it isn't already available:

```
<script type="text/javascript">!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Then you don't pay the performance hit if the user has previously visited a site that uses the same CDN, and you're not hosting the file yourself.

Comment: really interesting suggestion. not really what I want but really interesting. thanks for that